# django template show only distinct value

Tags: python, django, templates

Suppose I have a query:

```
cities = City.objects.all()
```

In my template I have done:

```
{% for city in cities %}
    {{city.friend_name}}
    <a href="{% url "my_url" city.friend_name.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">View Detail</a>
{% endfor %}
```

It gives me name of 4 friends with id say alex 1, matt 2, mack 3, mack 3. But here mack is repeated. I only want mack once. If the values are repeated I want it to be printed only once.

How can I do this in template. I mean is there something like `{{city.friend_name|distinct}}` or something else

I dont want unique city. I want friends name on city to be unique.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to do it in the template? Try to modify `cities` itself so that it has unique entries.
You could convert your `list` to a `set` and then re-convert it back:

`cities_unique = list(set(cities))`

If you have to show unique attributes, use the [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#regroup) feature

Comment: Kindly refrain from editing the question so as to ask a new question. As for the answer, check out the edit

Answer (score 14):

Don't use extra input parameters, just use the "ifchanged" django builtin filter: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged

```
{% for city in cities|dictsort:'friend_name' %}
    {% ifchanged %}{{city.friend_name}}{% endifchanged %}    
    <a href="{% url "my_url" city.friend_name.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">View Detail</a>
{% endfor %}
```

p.s. i know it's 3 years old but it's an helpful answer for someone else.

Comment: I am someone else and I found this answer helpful!

Answer (score 4):

It is usually best to change your Query first to ensure you get the least amount of data.
In this case, you could edit your query as follows:

```
cities_with_uniq_friend_names = City.objects.all().distinct('friend_name')
```

Now when you iterate over `cities_with_uniq_friend_names` it will give you unique friend names

Comment: This is the right way to do it - don't apply business logic in templates

Comment: but it is only supported by Postgres I am using mysql