# django distinct in template by filter

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I need to display unique values in template. I know **distinct** will work in query. But table in one row **Many to Many field** I don't know how to implement for that. If any possibilities are there to use it in template

```
class DoctorFeedback(models.Model):
 visited_for = models.CharField(max_length=200)
 tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tags)
class Tags(models.Model):
tag_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587385/django-template-show-only-distinct-value/50871558) question can help you

Comment: Do you want to get your data unique its by `tag` filed of  `DoctorFeedback`, right?

Comment: @MohitChandel, that's not useful

Answer (score 0):

You can add `unique=True` to Tags, so there will never be any duplicates:

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    tag_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
```