# Django template: not showing product if the product has already been shown

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

Really sorry about the disturbing title, my case is a bit tricky to explain (and i'm not that good in english). I'll try to do my best.

I have a django app where users can save paired food products - the first is the "product_to_substitute" and the second one is the "substitute_product". But the thing is that the "product_to_substitute" can actually have multiples "substitute_product". Here is what my "favorites" DB table can looklike (numbers are products IDs) :

| product_to_substitute_id | substitute_product_id |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 50 |
| 3 | 45 |
| 58 | 124 |
| 12 | 98 |

So what I would like to do on my favorites html page is to show one section with the "product_to_substitute" and a second section that shows all the "substitute_product" that are paired with the "product_to_substitute".

Here is a little bit of my code:

```
{% for product in favorites %}
        {% if product.product_to_substitute %}

            ### Block where I want to show only once the product to substitute ###
            <section style="background-image: url('{{ product.product_to_substitute.image_url }}')">
                ...
            </section>


            ### Block where I want to show all the substitutes products that are paired with the product to substitute ###
            <section>
                <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ product.substitute_product.image_url }}" alt="..." />
            </section>

        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

By looking at the example table, my code right now would show 5 paired blocks of "product_to_substitute" and "substitute_product", which is not I want. I would like to have 3 paired blocks. One for the product_to_substitute_id "3" and two for the product_to_substitute_id "58" and "12".

I hope that makes sense...

Thanks!

Comment: This answer might be helpful to you. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587385/django-template-show-only-distinct-value/50871558

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.